# SPARQL Filter in-Text multiple terms

Tags: text, filter, filtering, sparql

I would like to filter speeches for certain terms from a dictionary. Ideally, the outcome table would return the speeches from the dataset, containing one **or more** of the defined terms.

I have tried two versions so far.

One where I immediately try to match the respective terms:

```
SELECT ?name ?gender ?partyname ?countryname ?date ?speechnr
WHERE {
  ?speech tpf:match (lpv:text 'domestic abuse OR domestic violence OR intimate partner violence' ?text). 
  ?speech lpv:spokenAs ?function.
  ?function lpv:institution ?party. 
  ?party rdf:type lpv:NationalParty.
  ?party rdfs:label ?partyname.
  ?speech lpv:docno ?speechnr.
  ?speech dcterms:date ?date.
  ?speech lpv:speaker ?speaker.
  ?speaker lpv:name ?name.
  ?speaker lpv:gender ?gender.
  ?speaker lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?country. 
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryname.
   FILTER ( ?date >= "1999-07-20"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2004-07-19"^^xsd:date ) 
  } ORDER BY ?date ?speechnr LIMIT 10
```

and another where I try to filter for the terms in the end:

```
SELECT ?name ?gender ?partyname ?countryname ?date ?speechnr ?text 
WHERE {
  ?speech lpv:spokenText ?text.
  ?speech lpv:spokenAs ?function.
  ?function lpv:institution ?party. 
  ?party rdf:type lpv:NationalParty.
  ?party rdfs:label ?partyname.
  ?speech lpv:docno ?speechnr.
  ?speech dcterms:date ?date.
  ?speech lpv:speaker ?speaker.
  ?speaker lpv:name ?name.
  ?speaker lpv:gender ?gender.
  ?speaker lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?country. 
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryname.
  FILTER ( ?date >= "1999-07-20"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2004-07-19"^^xsd:date ) 
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?text), "en"))
  FILTER(?text = 'domestic abuse' || 'domestic violence' || 'intimate partner violence') 
  } ORDER BY ?date ?speechnr LIMIT 10
```

I also tried the following filter but don't know how I can include an OR there:

```
FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic abuse')).
```

The Problems:

1. if I use OR I only get returned speeches in which **one** of the given terms is contained.
2. Using the logical || did not even return speeches with the looked-for terms for some reason.
3. additionally, for terms like 'domestic violence', I only want them to be returned if adjacent (e.g., not just 'violence').

Sorry for this long text, I would really appreciate your help.
The website if needed https://linkedpolitics.project.cwi.nl/web/html/home.html

Comment: 1.) not sure what you mean, indeed OR is just any of them. If you mean that single tokens are sufficient to match, this is because it's a fulltext index search, just trying to find similar documents - this is no looking for phrases.

Comment: 2) how should this work? Your filter `FILTER(?text = 'domestic abuse' || 'domestic violence' || 'intimate partner violence') 
 ` is doing an exact match, indeed the whole text is way longer and just contains those phrases.

Comment: 3) same principle as you did before, `FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic abuse') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic violence'))` and so on and so forth

Comment: for efficiency reason I'd combine the fulltext search with the `FILTER(CONTAINS(...`

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your helpful comments. Do I understand correctly then, that there is no way to look for speeches that have one or more of these terms at once? It's always just one of them if I combine it with || or OR?

Comment: not sure if I understand, but OR resp. || is indeed no exclusive or - it can indeed contain multiple of your phrases. When you do `FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic abuse') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic violence'))` it can contain just 'domestic abuse' or 'domestic violence' or of course both

Comment: my other statement was that `tpf:match (lpv:text 'domestic abuse OR domestic violence OR intimate partner violence' ?text).` does not ensure phrase search. it is not looking for the phrase like "domestic abuse" but just for each token in a fulltext index and then ranked. Phrase search is not supported (yet) by this triple store. That's why I suggest to use this fulltext search but apply a `FILTER(CONTAINS` afterwards which guarantees full phrases being contained

Comment: This works great! Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!